# Set up some versions on rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production

Tags: mysql, ruby, mariadb, rake, redmine

im trying to update my Bitnami Redmine database, by using rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production but the problem is that the status says that i have many updates to do, but when i try theses updates i allways receive a message that the column or the table already exists, there is some command to "jump" db to especific version?

Answer (score 0):

You can always "inject" a version into the `schema_migrations` table to trick the migration system into ignoring them, but TBH I'd be looking into why the migrations are so out of whack.

Worst case, you could always add `column_exists?` checks to each failing migration, and not add or update a column if it already has been added. But again, you run the risk of your migrations being out of spec with the state of the actual database.